# Firefox extension: observing "user-interaction-inactive" across multiple browser windows

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm trying to observe within my Firefox extension when a user is inactive. My current solution is derived from a similar question, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183230/how-can-i-observe-a-specified-firefox-event-in-a-firefox-extension) (see accepted answer). And it basically works just fine.

I noticed, however, that it doesn't seem to distinguish between multiple open browser windows - that is, a user cannot be active in one window and inactive in another one. At the moment the active/inactive state is some global state across all Firefox windows. Thus, a user becomes really inactive, if the user is active in *all* open browser windows

Is there a way to distinguish between different windows, or do I have to deal with it (wouldn't be to bad, but still...)? Thanks a lot for any hints on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that you will have to implement yourself. It also largely depends on what you mean by "inactive in a particular window". I guess that you mean the lack of mouse and keyboard activity in this window. So you would have to add a listener for `keydown`, `keyup`, `mousemove`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `DOMMouseScroll`, `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove` events. The listener for these events would set a timeout, e.g. for one minute. However, it would first clear the already existing timeout if any. This way the timeout will fire one minute after the last event received, one minute after the user stopped generated keyboard or mouse events in the window.

Comment: "This is something that you will have to implement yourself." That is basically all I needed to know :), i.e. that it's not a simple tweak of the current solution. And you are right, of course, that this question involves some design decisions. The good thing is that I'm not forced to a specific solution. I like to log my browsing behaviour "as detailed as possible", and the current solution is not that bad. So I might keep it that way, accepting the somewhat limited "resolution". Thanks a lot for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `subject` parameter the observer passes should be the window of the currently active browser window.

Comment: The question is about detecting whether the user isn't doing anything with a particular window, not about determining the active browser window.

Comment: Hi! To check out the `subject` and `data` parameter was the thing I tried first. But both parameters are `null` all the time, at least for what I'm observing (`user-interaction-active`, `user-interaction-inactive`).